# Datatables warning when cell contains comma

Tags: javascript, csv, datatables

I have a feature on a web application that allows a user to upload a csv to the server. Upon selecting the csv file to upload, I open the file using javascript and then create a table via datatables so that the user can preview/confirm what they are wanting to upload.

Before the table is drawn, I convert the csv file into a multi-dimensional array using [this](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-ask-ben-parsing-csv-strings-with-javascript-exec-regular-expression-command.htm) function and then use that as the dataset.

My problem is that when one of those csv values contains a comma I get a datatables warning saying:

> DataTables warning: table id=csv-data-display-table - Requested
>   unknown parameter '17' for row 6. For more information about this
>   error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4 - Error object: undefined

Below is some example data that causes the issue:

```
test1,companynamewith'test01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
test2,"companynamewith,test02",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
test3,companynamewith/test03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Notice that the middle line has a comma in the second column but that it is also wrapped in quotes.

Here is the problem record after it hits the function that builds an array out of it:

```
["test2", "companynamewith,test02", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

I would have thought that Datatables would be smart enough to parse through an array like that without getting hung up on the comma because it's inside quotes but maybe not. As soon as I remove that line from the csv, it works exactly as intended and without any warning. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It has nothing to do with dataTables not being " smart enough". You do realize, that if you are using arrays you need to provide an array of arrays? I.e `[[test2", "companynamewith,test02", "", ""]]`. If you still think this not is an "error 40", then please provide an example where the behaviour is reproduced.

Comment: It is an array of arrays, I just pulled out the one that is giving me an issue for the example.

Comment: Also, like I said above, my code works exactly as intended as soon as I remove that line from the csv (and/or array)

Comment: I'd not use that function. There are a few decent ones which will cope with such data. Perhaps the best is PapaParse. It rocks and should be able to cope with your data.

Comment: The function that converts the csv to an array? I don't think that's my issue here since it still creates the array as it should (with the comma inside of the quoted element). I think the issue has to be with Datatables as I immediately hand the data off to it after I hit that function. Also, the error isn't thrown until Datatables starts working with it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is mismatch in number of fields in your data (`17`) and number of columns in your table (`18` or more).

Please read [this technical note](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4#Parameter-is-an-integer) for more information.

[This example](https://jsfiddle.net/0nb1nspu/2/) with wrong number of columns produces the same error, and [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/0nb1nspu/3/) with matching number of columns doesn't.

Comment: I believe the mismatch is because Datatables is seeing the comma and thinks its a new element in the array. As a result, it sees that particular record as having one extra column. If I remove the line from the csv that has the comma inside of the quotes, the error goes away. The other records have the exact same number of comma delimited elements as the one that breaks datatables.

Comment: @Reasoned, the array you've listed in the question has `17` fields. The error message contains reference to 18th element. Your data is fine, see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/0nb1nspu/3/) with your array.